# Get Minimum value from 2 unsigned int

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to implement a function that have to return the minimum value from a list of array, without comparers (“==”, “!=”, “>”, “<”, “>=”, “<=”), but to simplify I will work with only two variables.
Suppose I have two values : the number 5 declared as "a" and the number 35 declared as "b", so I found a way to get  the minimum of two integers, but not two unsigned integers, see:

```
b + ((a - b) & ((a - b) >> 31));
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Something like http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax?

Comment: note that this code for `int` is prone to integer overflow and (signed) integer overflows are undefined behavior. For example the case with `a == 0` and `b == INT_MIN` might not return the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cheap & cheesy solution: If you are using 32-bit unsigned integers you can cast them to 64-bit signed integers and use the code you have above.

Comment: (+1) for reducing the problem to one that's already been solved. :)

Comment: nice, this is a perfect solution!

Comment: @MarkB in the code above there's no unspecified behavior related to the right-shit. But the right-shift operation above is implementation defined with a signed negative left operand. But if the compiler is `gcc`, `gcc` says it does the sign extension.

Answer (score 1):

Type casting is a costly operation. We want to calculate minimum using bit-wise ope